# The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1) jammy Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: 20.04, updates, lts

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS which  I found out that it is different from Jammy Jellyfish.

I get the following error:

```
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1) jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What can I do? I just started learning Linux and how to use the terminal.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.x is the Jammy Jellyfish release of Ubuntu. Whatever led you believe differently has misled you.

Comment: In a nutshell: Open Software & Updates and remove the selection you added before. The CD-ROM selection is never there by default.

Comment: ah! Thank you. :)